# malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is a strange error I'm having on a server.

**Summary**

I'm running a mere

```
python manage.py
```

to which Django correctly replies with a usage message, but at the end of the usage message I get `malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size`.

**Details**

```
root@charles:oauthtutorial# /opt/oauthtutorial/venv/bin/python manage.py

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    [...removing more output...]
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted
```

If `INSTALLED_APPS` contains only `django.contrib.admin`, `django.contrib.contenttypes`, `django.contrib.messages` and `django.contrib.staticfiles` (and my app, which it is a completely empty app created by `django-admin`), the error doesn't occur. If `INSTALLED_APPS` contains `django.contrib.sessions` or `django.contrib.auth`, then the error occurs.

The problem does not occur on my laptop, only on the server.

**Environment**

Debian 11.2

Linux 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux

(Debian-packaged) Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux

Django 3.2.12

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're still struggeling with this but in case you are:

Had the same error and seems disabling django.contrib.auth bypass the problem. In fact the error is due to PostGIS. On Debian11, remove libgdal20 and install libgdal28.

```
apt purge libgdal20
apt install libgdal28
```

If you´re not using PostGIS then I don't know. Try enabling on module at a time with an empty django project and see where it starts failling